# How to populate the list of selected items? ng2-dual-list-box angular

Tags: angular

I need to populate the list of selected items, how can I do this?

```
<ng2-dual-list-box 
      [data]="items"
      (onAvailableItemSelected)="onAvailableItemSelected($event)"
      (onSelectedItemsSelected)="onSelectedItemsSelected($event)"
      (onItemsMoved)="onItemsMoved($event)">
</ng2-dual-list-box>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "populate"?

Comment: Please provide more specific question. With your example, and what error you get

Comment: I have no error, I need to start the view with elements in both list and not only in the list of available elements

Comment: @OresteNillarCambara - Did you get working solution to your question. I am going to use and was wondering the same like you in this question.

Answer (score 0):

[(ngModel)]="selected"

See the documentation [Here](https://github.com/matsura/ng2-dual-list-box):

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late answer but may be some one will find it helpful answer
I faced same problem and couldn't find solution for it even in GitHup page
[how to populate the list of selected items? ng2-dual-list-box angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592031/how-to-populate-the-list-of-selected-items-ng2-dual-list-box-angular)

so I edited the library by myself and it works fine now till they solve it may be in the next verison
so if anyone have the same problem just contact me and I will tell you what I did